# How would one calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n((1+\frac{1}{n})^n-e)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

What I have thought about this is:

1. we may use L'Hopstal's rule to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{((1+\frac{1}{n})^n-e)}{\frac{1}{n}}$, both the numerator and denominator goes to 0 as n goes to infinity. But calculating the derivative of $(1+1/n)^n$ seems to be very complicated.
2. Using Taylor series to calculate the dominant terms of $(1+1/n)^n$, but I'm not really sure if it makes sense to let $"n=\infty"$. Equivalently maybe we can expand $(1+x)^{1/x}$ at $x=0$, but it's not defined.

Maybe I wasn't on the right track. Even if the solution uses a different approach, I would still love to know how to expand $(1+x)^{1/x}$. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: See [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7Dn((1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D)%5En-e)%24&p=1) for more related links.

Comment: Hi Thanks that solves my problem. Still I'm curious how we can expand $(1+x)^{1/x}$  EDIT: Nvm seems like we can do a $e^{\log(\dot)}$ and use taylor series twice, thanks!

Comment: We may use Salahamam_ Fatima's hint, or you may consider finding the Maclaurin expansion of $$f(x)=\begin{cases}(1+x)^{1/x},&x\ne0\\e,&x=0\end{cases}$$which should give you the same conclusion as the aforementioned answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$f (x)=(1+x)^\frac 1x=e^{\frac {1}{x}\ln (1+x)} $$

$$\ln (1+x)=x-\frac {x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon (x)) $$

$$f (x)=e.e^{-\frac {x}{2}(1+\epsilon (x))} $$

$$=e\Bigl (1-\frac {x}{2}(1+\epsilon (x)\Bigr)$$

The limit will be $$-\frac {e}{2} $$

Comment: @Isham What didn't you understand.

Comment: @Fatima Well I think I should read it again to understand clearly what you wrote...